# How to get files from sub-directory into ArrayList using java?

Tags: java

I have a package, which contains a lot of java swing components all of them extend a range of different JSwing components. In a separate file I want to access all of these components and put them into an `ArrayList`?

I can do it in any way i want but i do not see how i could get it from looping through every file and I also do not know how to do it if I import it into an ArrayList dynamically.

For example:

```
-MyComponentsPackage
  -Component1 (This extends JLabel)
  -Component2 (This extends JButton)
  -...
```

in another file I need to do:

```java
private List<JComponent> = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
```

I want to be able to loop through every object and add them to a JPanel:

```java
for (Component componentInPackage : allComponentsInPackage) {
    myPanel.add(componentInPackage);
}
```

Comment: Try reflection?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I want to be able to loop through every object and add them to a JPanel_ Why do you need to do this? You will need to create an instance of each `JComponent` and add it to the `JPanel`.

Comment: @Abra I have hundreds of components and I thought there would be a more efficient way that writing that many lines of code for it.

Comment: So you want a `JPanel` that contains hundreds of components?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking out this post: [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

It provides a solution that you could use, but also goes into an explanation.

Comment: How would I access the actual object to a JPanel?

Comment: If you have managed to retrieve all relevant classes you can create instances of them using `Class#newInstance()´ (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance)